# Add a number foreach level of the Tikz tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, tikzpagenodes

I'm trying to do a states tree as follows.

[image]

My actual issue is that I don't know how to add the number placed on the left side of the tree (as in the picture).
The numbers are placed at the level of the arrows and not at the same level as the nodes.
In addition, can you tell me how I can make the marked arrows thicker?

This is the snippet of code that I wrote:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={draw, circle}, ->,accepting/.style={double distance=2pt, outer sep=0.75pt+\pgflinewidth}]
\node{$q_0$}
    child { node {$q_0$} 
        child { node {$q_0$}
            child { node {$q_0$}
                child{node {$q_0$}}
            } 
            child { node {$q_1$}
                child{node [accepting]{$q_2$}}
            }
        }
    }
    child [missing]
    child { node {$q_1$}
        child { node {$q_2$} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With forest is simple:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    circle,
    draw, 
    math content,
    edge = {draw, semithick, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
    /tikz/E/.style = {draw=red, very thick, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
    l sep=7mm,
    s sep=12mm
            }
[q_0, name=n0
    [q_0, name=n1, edge=E
        [q_0, name=n2, edge=E
            [q_0, name=n3
                [q_0, name=n4]
            ]
            [q_1, edge=E
                [q_2, double, edge=E]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [,phantom]
    [q_1 
        [q_2]
    ]
]
\tikzset{
    L/.style = {auto, font=\large\sffamily\bfseries},
        }
\coordinate[left=of n4] (aux);
\path (aux) to[L, "1"] (aux |- n3)
            to[L, "0"] (aux |- n2)
            to[L, "1"] (aux |- n1)
            to[L, "0"] (aux |- n0);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]